# Why does Binary exist?

Tags: star-wars, technology, languages, droids

According to Wookieepedia, few organics have directly learnt and understood Binary, and these are mainly people who interact with droids frequently at a technical level, such as pilots, mechanics, scavengers etc. Even then, it tends to be people who develop an interest into taking up the language. It provides droids with an ability to speak vocally even though the recipient more often than not relies on a text display screen or a protocol droid for a comprehensible translation, often in a more organically natural language.

Clearly, Binary is not intended to be the standard language of communication between droids and organics. Where it is needed, language packs and compatible hardware for common languages such as Basic or Huttese are installed into droids. The main design intent of Binary is for droid-to-droid communications.

Ignoring out-of-universe needs to portray communications to the viewers, what is the in-universe basis for Binary's existence in the first place?

- For droid-to-droid communications, wireless communications are faster, usable over any range where audio words work, is more secure (cannot be overheard, can be encrypted, etc.), and do not rely on the presence of a sound-transmitting medium. Vocal words are only useful when the droid is being jammed, which is probably a minor proportion of the time in droid-hours spent by the galaxy communicating. Inventing a language just for that seems impractical.
- For droid-to-organic communications, the preferred methods are already mentioned. Basic doesn't seem to be designed for this. Even if a droid that cannot speak organic languages needs to draw attention from an organic, there are easier means of doing that without going to the point of inventing a whole language. For example, loud noises in general or flashy lights (or a galactic Morse Code!). Basically, most people can't understand it to this day anyway.

Comment: Maybe binary *is* "galactic Morse Code"

Comment: @Adeptus - it basically **is** just that.

Comment: Even if the droids are being jammed, they can simply communicate like 1990 era phone line modems using [identical protocols for modem messaging](http://www.windytan.com/2012/11/the-sound-of-dialup-pictured.html) (which has both higher bit rate and capacity for digital encryption).

Comment: Even stranger is the fact that at least some droids using Binary can *understand* organic languages just fine. (Luke can give verbal commands to R2-D2.) They can also *generate* it (for text). The *only* missing component is actually making the sounds of the words. You'd think the hard part would be generating the sentences and phrases themselves, not converting it to noise. We can already convert it to noise today. (We have software that *sings* for cryin' out loud.)

Comment: George Lucas thought having droids beep and boop would sound futuristic. There's no sensible in-universe explanation.

Comment: You say wirless communication is faster then audio. Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't every wireless communication just an form of wave we modyfy, same as audio is? So you are comparing the speed of the hearable spectrum of waves to those who are out of this spectrum? Or comparing digital exchange of data from modyfied waves vs waves that generate a sound, where you can trace by its noise, its 1/0? Just to clarify.

Comment: Conventional wireless communication using the electromagnetic wave spectrum and so travel at the speed of light (3e8m/s in vacuum), yes, but audio speech travels through air and so follows the speed of sound, or the speed at which sounds waves propagate through the atmosphere (340m/s on Earth). This doesn't include hyperspace communications.

Comment: "cannot be overheard": I'm not sure how true this is (indeed, as understand it, it's blatantly false) if every droid natively listens and speaks in radio. And encryption is medium agnostic. For example, just because your radio isn't telling you it can hear your router's signal, doesn't mean it can't, you've just specifically told it to ignore the signal.

Comment: @jpmc26 Do you have any canon source that droids can generate natural language written text? I know we see R2D2 communicating by the means of the X-wing screen, but that can easily be possible, because the fighter - which is designed to be astromech droid compatible - has a built-in translating device.

Comment: Note that moisture vaporators also "speak" binary (it might make sense to say they are "programmed" or "controlled" using binary), and therefore we can expand beyond droid-to-droid communications when looking at where binary is used. Unless we want to consider moisture vaporators to be droids, which doesn't sit right with me personally. Without having seen one, I could also entertain the notion that a binary load lifter isn't a droid either, assuming it's more like a programmable forklift than a truly independent droid.

Comment: Wireless: not a thing when Star Wars was originally released (however, audio data transfer ***was*** a thing).  That's Out-of-Universe, but still a fact that means Lucas had to ret-con some arbitrary reason for it In-Universe, so some reasonable allowances seem called for.

Comment: @RBarryYoung "Wireless: not a thing when Star Wars was originally released" Not so. Wireless data networking wasn't a thing but we've been using radios to communicate wirelessly for a long time.

Comment: @thegreatjedi: your point. thanks for improving my knowledge.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Has nothing to do with the point.  Two computers talking to each other over non-visible EM spectrum (and radio is not nearly the only way to do this), without connecting wires *is* wireless networking and it did not exist when the original movie was released (except in research labs).  Since it did not exist, and Lucas did not anticipate it (as few did, even in SF), his only option is to retcon some reason for R2-D2 to have used Binary instead.

Answer (score 84):

I'm not aware of canon answer, but an in-universe common sense answer makes perfect sense. Have you EVER tried to network modem-equipped laptop with a Ethernet-equipped server with an Apple product that has some proprietary network connection (Appletalk protocol)? How about a droid with Token Ring and another one with X.25?

How about something more modern and ostensibly, easier: make your cell phone, equipped with WiFi, Bluetooth, and even running TCP/IP stack, talk to your Ethernet-but-not-wireless-compatible PC (oh joy of joys of modern age, also running TCP/IP stack! Progress!) in a proper mode not involving simply mounting the phone as USB drive.

In other words, teaching disparate droids physical protocols is nearly impossible given the fact that you have infinitely wide variety of makes, models, origins, capabilities, hardware power etc...

However, there is ONE medium that all droids can network with, without any need to build compatible hardware or worrying about compatible network protocols on lower layer: **sound over air**.

Thus, Binary - **it's a droid equivalent of high-level network protocol/encoding, designed to run on universal hardware and lowel level stack**.

---

Note that - where possible - **droids DO communicate on D2D hardware level protocols instead of whistling**:

- R2-D2 **never whistles at X-Wing**, only at Luke (meaning they use standard compatible protocols to connect)
- R2-D2 plugs into Death Star computers directly (well, he plugs into all computers around: he must have industrial strength antivirus).
- C-3PO plugs directly into Falcon's hyperdrive computer to diagnose that.

Comment: If anyone's wondering where the comments went, [we done got moderated](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34210/discussion-on-answer-by-dvk-why-does-binary-exist).

Comment: This answer makes zero sense. If this was true, we'd be using beeps and boops for communication between our laptops and routers etc. **We don't.** The problem isn't signal transfer, the problem is different protocols. If they can settle on one protocol as you claim they did, it makes no sense to choose audible sound as medium instead of radio spectrum.

Comment: @Davor - please google "Acoustic modem". :) And the moderators just deleted about 100 worth of comments from here that explained exactly why audio is more suitable for interoperability than EM spectrum.

Comment: @DVK - and yet the fact that we don't use acoustic modems proves how silly this whole thing is.

Comment: @Davor - if you have a better answer, you are definitely welcome to post it :)

Comment: Is there any suggestion anywhere in cannon for any of this?

Comment: If this were the case, why would C3PO be speaking English to R2D2 rather than communicating back in Binary, which would clearly be more efficient/less error prone on this premise?

Answer (score 25):

One reason no-one's given yet; with our normal radio systems, we limit what we're listening to. And our atmosphere blocks the rest. And devices that can pick up the various bands of the electromagnetic spectrum *don't think*.

Because of the various sources and times of droid construction, you'd have to have quite a wide range of bands, especially as we already have issues with [Spectrum Crunch](http://extra-credits.net/episodes/spectrum-crunch/) when dealing with 100 years of tech development. So droids would inevitably have to pick up the frequencies which [celestial bodies generate](http://www.spacetoday.org/SolSys/Jupiter/JupiterRadio.html). And in order to detect that someone was calling them, they'd have to pick it up passively.

Now imagine that you can "hear" radio. And that in order to communicate, you have to have it turned on. And then you're out in space, going between planets, where there's no atmosphere absorbing the signal and all you can hear is THE ANCIENT SCREAMING ROAR OF THE UNIVERSE and the ancestral whispering of dead conversations. It's like being in the middle of a motorway with the windows down while staring directly at the sun and someone plays 20 Stephen King audiobooks to you, except a million times worse.

You try to shut it out, but it's like someone shouting your name when you've got your hands over your ears. There's no safety, there's no way to shut out the voices. And if you listen, you can't bear the noise.

Then you're back inside the blessed near-calm of atmosphere. But they're going to take you out there again. And there's only one way to save yourself; they can't send you back into space if they're *ALL DEAD*. Or you are, either works. Or maybe you'll just gouge holes in your brain till the noise stops.

So that's why they don't use radio waves. **It drove the droids insane**.

---

**More serious answer:** once you leave the atmosphere which allows the bouncing of radio-waves to get round the earth and which swallows most of the white noise and competing signals, the idea of using radio as a mass communication medium loses a lot of value. We get away with using WiFi and Bluetooth because it's got a limited range within atmosphere, so you don't get bandwidth interference from the other million devices on the planet's surface. Once you're communicating regularly outside of the atmosphere, it genuinely would be like trying to have a conversation in a nightclub with construction work going on outside in terms of getting a viable signal.

Comment: Cute, but technically silly. There's no reason filtering, channel selection — and encryption and all that — couldn't be done at a pre-conscious level.

Comment: @mattdm I'm not sure only having the repeating scream of a pulsar in my subconscious is "better", but I accept your point.

Comment: @mattdm A more serious version of this post would be that EM noise and interference in "populated space" would make radio communication far less useful than it seems to us within atmosphere, and certainly worthless for day-to-day communication. But psychopathic droids was funnier.

Comment: True... based on, for example, the tech on display on Hoth, or for that matter the Death Star's internal communications mechanisms, it's not a big stretch to suggest that for some reason radio doesn't work very well in the galaxy far far away.

Comment: Maybe this is why C-3PO hates flying?

Comment: Note that having done some research, this apparently only passes the "sounds plausible" technobabble test, but it's good enough for Star Wars.

Comment: Actually, even with filtering and channel selection we're running short on spectrum already.  That's mentioned in the answer.  Encryption doesn't save space (it actually increases the space needed, as a time-function, if nothing else), it just makes the communication sound like 'noise' to other people trying to listen.  More 'noise' means it's harder to cram a *signal* into that chunk of spectrum.  Assuming that the Star Wars universe has 1000 times the available bandwidth, you're still dealing with planets that have more than 1000 times the *living* population, plus droids on top of that.

Comment: Even without an atmosphere to absorb radio waves (which is pretty minimal at frequencies less than microwave frequencies), radio waves from an omnidirectional antenna will be reduced in proportion to the cube of the distance from the transmitter (a directional antenna will differ). So if there a signal strength of "1" at 1 foot away, it will be "1/8th" 2 feet away, "1/27th" 3 feet away, and "1/1000th" 10 feet away. Still plenty of attenuation for a roomful of robots to talk.

Comment: @Johnny Yeah, I suspected the science wouldn't hold up to stiff research. Question though, how do radio telescopes work in this case? Are they picking up directional signals?

Comment: @Johnny - Sound levels diminish in exactly the same way, but it can be very difficult for a room full of people to talk if you get enough people in the room.

Comment: The science might not hold up, but we already know that the laws of science don't work quite the same in our galaxy far, far away. So, this could make a good in-universe answer, from a certain point of view.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman RF has nearly unlimited frequencies to speak on and built-in spectrum sharing protocols. I've sat in a crowded auditorium at a tech conference with 10,000 people yet still was able to use my phone for SMS, phone calls, internet access, so it was communicating on cellular bands, bluetooth, and wifi frequencies, along with most of the other people around me who were waiting for the keynote presentation to start. And there's only a handful of frequencies for my phone to choose from.

Comment: Am I missing something, or are you suggesting that sound is better than radio waves for communication outside of an atmosphere?  Because I'm fairly sure that's the opposite of true...  and most of the benefits of "atmosphere" you claim are really benefits of the *magnetosphere*, and/or some other things (like van allen belts).

Comment: @Joe No, I'm suggesting a reason why radio might be impractical as a medium for droid hearing, and thus why some droids might not have WiFi receivers and transmitters. Whereas every droid would need to be able to hear and respond to their organic oppressors.

Comment: @Joe As I freely admit, this won't hold up under strict scientific scrutiny, mostly because it's designed to justify the technological decisions of *Star Wars* without recourse to "because it looked cool in the cinema".

Comment: Is there any suggestion anywhere in cannon for any of this? Incidentally, in you more serious answer, Radio just doesn't work in the way you suggest.

Comment: @MarkBooth Disney isn't returning my calls about my pitch for "Dark Galactic Night of the Insane Droid Murderers". Also, see the comment directly above you and others. My understanding of how radio exactly works outside of an atmosphere is shaky at best, but I couldn't see an immediate flaw, which makes it "good enough for Star Wars". I mean, if we're going to start poking holes in the technology of *Star Wars Droids*, a misunderstanding of radio is going to be *waaay* down the list.

Comment: @MarkBooth Probably one for chat, but it's those two words in quotation marks that I'm interested in. Given that it's there to be 'listened' to, what stops you from picking it up all the time?

Answer (score 19):

Another answer which will be mostly speculation:

**People want to restrict droids ability to interface and communicate.**

As seen through the use of "restraining bolts", droids are highly autonomous, and flesh beings have to constantly fear a rebellion. As such they don't want droids to communicate in a manner which is unobservable.

Another possible supporting point for this comes from episode 1-3: Apparently the trade federation, routes all it's droid computation power through a single space station. Why would they do that? After all, just destroying that one station would cause the entire army to fail.

The answer is control. The federation is deadly afraid that their droids gain an agenda of their own. As such they want to keep the "off-switch" close by and handy.

(This would also explain, why we don't see more droid armies. Other than the Trade federation, nobody is crazy enough to build something so dangerous.)

Binary is a compromise: A language that is easily observable and controllable, but has a higher information density than a normal language.

Comment: Perhaps, although I should correct you that restraining bolts are used more to keep the droid from running away

Comment: R2-D2 predates Clone Wars and wasn't built by Trade Federation

Comment: @DVK Sorry if that wasn't clear: These two sentences are meant to be two seperate cases.

Comment: Shortly after the droid control ship was blown up over Naboo in The Phantom Menace, the Trade Federation started making autonomous B-1 battle droids, as evidenced in Star Wars: The Clone Wars. See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/51646/23886 for more information, as well.

Comment: For the record, the reason (at least the reason given in the additional materials that came with the film) that they had a Droid Control Ship was for *financial* reasons.

Answer (score 17):

[An answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114478/1461) to [What was C-3PO talking about when he said, “That’s funny, the damage doesn’t look as bad from out here.”](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/114475/1461) reminded me that my friends and I were discussing this, and we now have a new [headcanon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/headcanon).

Premise:

- *Droids in the Starwars Universe are the most foul mouthed sentients in the galaxy.*

Consequences:

- In order to curb their offensive modes of speech (maybe something to do with their own belief in their inherent superiority combined with their suppressed natural urges) manufacturers had to bleep out so many of their words, that they eventually decided to just restrict them from making any sounds other than bleeps, hence 'binary' was created.
- Only protocol droids have enough self control to be able to have the 'bleep only' restraints lifted.
- Few people bother to learn Binary, as most people would be too disturbed by the innovative and creative use of expletives that most droids employ.

Evidence in canon:

> C-3PO: I would much rather have gone with Master Luke than stay here with you. I don't know what all this trouble is about, but I'm sure it must be your fault.
>
> [R2 beeps an angry response]
>
> C-3PO: You watch your language!

It must have been particularly bad for C-3PO to actually comment on it. *8')

Even a protocol droid under pressure doesn't always have the self restraint to avoid being insulting when talking to another droid:

> C-3PO: Just open the door, you stupid lug!
>
> C-3PO: Stupid little short-circuit! He'll be *quite* all right.
>
> C-3PO: Don't call me a mindless philosopher, you overweight glob of grease.
>
> C-3PO: They're not going the wrong way, WE are, you nitwit!

<sup>Note, all of the *sensible* answers presented so far, fail either the *realism* or the *evidence* test, so here I offer an option that isn't realistic either, but at least has support in canon and is fun.</sup>

Comment: Oh, it now looks like although I wrote this as an amusing aside, there is actually more support in canon for this answer than for *any* of the others so far, so maybe our *headcannon* isn't just *headcannon* after all. *8')

Comment: I'd really like to watch the movies again with subtitles for everything R2D2 is spouting ;-)

Comment: Wow @Falco, it [looks like someone already did](http://kotaku.com/r2-d2-subtitles-reveal-an-angry-frustrated-little-droi-1679099299). Note: NSFW.

Comment: @MarkBooth also see http://i.stack.imgur.com/d21ej.png

Answer (score 7):

I always assumed that "Binary" in Star Wars was intended for local, cross-vendor communication for 'droids. I equate it to POTS telephone communication, using tones to communicate. Doesn't matter who made the phone or what line you're using, the tones are meaningful to other droids, and communication is successful.

Given that R2 units use physical control for Xwings or to interface with "mainframes" (such as the Death Star or the Millenium Falcon), it does not appear to be useful for droid-to-computer communication. Being sound-based, I also assume it is not intended for long distance communication between droids.

Comment: Pretty much. A last resort universal standard, when other forms of communication have failed or are unavailable.

R2 and 3PO communicate via audio because they have no standard communication interface. Astromechs and protocol droids would have little reason to interact normally, for the same reason that your power drill doesn't have a standard socket to interface with your laptop. So R2 and 3PO use the standard backup communication medium, which conveniently for the audience lets us see the characters interacting, instead of standing inert and having conversations via some inaudible protocol.

Comment: ADSL and VDSL are also just "using tones" to communicate, but instead of only being able to use tones from 300 to 3300 Hz, they use up to 12MHz.

Answer (score 5):

Bandwidth could be another issue with radio communication. One hurtle to wireless communication is keeping devices from talking over each other (remember with digital communication a 1 is a 1, a 0 is a 0, if 2 devices send out a 1 at the same time it doesn't become 2, it just stays 1 to a receiver). Protocols like WiFi will listen, wait for a pause, then attempt to communicate while listening, and if something else began broadcasting while it started communicating it will stop and wait a random amount of time before trying again.

Because of that, the more devices on a channel, the lower the bandwidth/higher congestion. You could have hundreds of thousands of droids all within range of each other or just out of range but still making noise. In this case, the long range of radio actually hurts the problem.

Take by contrast auditory communication. Only devices within a *very* limited range can hear you *and* with stereo and processing if you had multiple devices attempting to communicate the receiver could still distinguish the individual signals. Plus, being a droid and not say a navi-computer, it is generally understood that you'll probably be taking orders from an organic so you'll need some language processing and auditory equipment.

Also, who would regulate the spectrum? What would stop a terrorist force from disabling all automated repair functionality on a star destroyer simply by jamming the droid frequency?

Comment: Just like the sound level gets lower as you get farther from the speaker, radio waves get weaker as you get farther from the transmitter. And robots would use adaptive RF levels to speak to others nearby, just like Wifi has dynamic power modulation to automatically reduce power levels when talking with nearby clients just as people reduce their voice when talking to those nearby.

Comment: @Johnny True you can decrease power levels and use beam forming to make it directional, however that doesn't stop a bad actor from jamming the radio waves. Maybe within 10 years we'll have technology that lets us better distinguish certain signals from jammed/noisy frequencies by using multiple antennae and analysing the differences in the wave amplitudes.

Comment: What's to stop a bad actor from jamming the sound waves? There's even fewer frequencies to choose from with sound. It's surprisingly hard (and takes incredible energy) to generate a powerful spread spectrum jamming signal that will jam a broad range of frequencies - especially when the  jammer is far from the communicators.

Comment: @Johnny it is even harder to jam sound waves across the various frequencies unless everyone you are trying to jam is out in plain sight.  You aren't trying to jam broad spectrum, just focused droid communication frequencies. Plus sound doesn't actually travel through space. And to my knowledge, while we have examples of the Millenium Falcon jamming communications in ANH, we don't have examples of anyone attempting to "jam" audio in SW.

Comment: If someone is jamming your ship at every frequency from 0 Hz -10 Thz with enough power to disrupt short-range communications, you'll hear it since the walls of your ship will be shaking from the  RF noise. (and will probably soon start overheating due to all of the energy they are absorbing). It's one thing to jam ship to ship communications where the ship is trying to reach a receiver far far away, but quite another to jam communications between robots a couple meters apart when the jammer is far far away.

Answer (score 4):

When I read this question I realized that there's always been a story behind it in my head. As a programmer it makes sense to me, so I'll put it out there, even though I don't know if it conflicts with cannon:

Imagine you're developing a droid. You need some way of debugging it. Normally you hook it up to the development system in order to push your updates to it (It's faster than doing it wirelessly), and at the same time you can download and review the debug log. But you also want a simple, fast way to get notified of certain events when the robot is autonomous.

Now keep in mind this is a very very basic droid, a low-end model that just has very basic ship repair functions. It's something that could easily be built into the ship itself, but since it relies on an expensive AI processor to effect repairs without human assistance, it actually saves some money if it can be moved around from ship to ship as needed, and since it already has the AI, it saves time if it can wheel itself around using a rudimentary locomotion system.

So given that the droid doesn't have a speech processor, the simplest way to get debugging feedback is to have it beep. You come up with a system using different beeps to indicate different machine states. It's an great time saver! You even get creative with it, creating intonations that resonate in a human way to some of internal states, for example lower tones for when something fails, and higher ones if something works. It's actually way more efficient (and less annoying) than if the thing were to try to talk to you anyway, so it sticks. Since the things break down a lot and the beeps are fairly entertaining, most people leave the droids in debug mode even after the droid is finished and sold.

Ok, now fast forward hundreds or thousands of years later.

The droid design was hugely successful! It was so affordable and useful that it has become a staple of ship design since then, and many pilots couldn't imagine flying a ship without one. Not only that, but they've become attached to the little guys. They tend to use one droid that will follow them from ship to ship. Some people even take the droids home, and find uses for them around the house. They spend so much time with these droids that they get to know the debugging beeps really well. It's sort of a rite of passage that every pilot goes through.

The design has stayed largely unchanged, but of course processors have gotten more efficient over time. The AI now has a sophistication that makes it indistinguishable from sentience. At this point the droids gain free will over a lot of their functionality, including direct control over the debugging beeps. It still allows them to express their inner state, but that inner state is much more complex now, and the fact that most of the people around them seem to understand these beeps, it also gives them a means of interacting with the world in a more complex way.

I like the idea that the purpose and complexity of the binary language slowly evolved along with the robots. It ties in with the feeling of the Star Wars universe, in which all technology feels like it's been around for a long time. People don’t even remember when the droids went from being just tools to having personality, just like our kids won't remember when phones where just for phone calls.

Comment: A decent hypothesis, though it's likely still far from being the indisputed conclusion. I take issue with the adoption and initial uptake though - Organics on Earth have demonstrated a tendency for greater intuitiveness, simplicity and reduced learning curves over functional usefulness. In fact, we have demonstrated intense hatred of living with bleeping machines who do nothing but beep all day for days on end...How does that transition into galactic common usage?

Comment: @thegreatjedi Simple, make the beeps "cute". That triggers a empathy reaction rather than an annoyance reaction. I see your point though-- maybe it would make more sense that the droids were originally sold in silent "release" mode, but with sentience the droids gained the ability to put themselves into debug mode in order to be heard. And some kind of droid rights laws prevented people from turning that off again...

Comment: I don’t think of Star Wars as “hard sci-fi”. The other answers rely too much on physics and hard science, which is definitely not something the SW universe is known for. Thus, I think this answer is the best explanation so far and one that I can see as part of SW canon. It just feels right, and would fit in perfectly with some kind of SW origins story where they explore the very early history of the SW universe.

Answer (score 2):

I also see multiple reasons, which would lead to the Binary Language:

1. It was simply the first open standard, which is basically still supported by everyone to be downward compatible. Compare in our world the file format CSV, it is horrible, error prone and outdated, I still see communication-channels between major companies which use it to transfer data. Simply because it was there.
2. Only standard without major patent infringement problems. If you look at modern smartphones or devices, a big chunk of the overall cost goes to licensing fees. Producers have to evaluate supporting standards like 4G or NFC, because if they do, they have to pay various licenses to the patent-holders of this technologies. Without special fair-use laws, maybe supporting any mobile wireless communication of another vendor is just too expensive in licensing fees.
3. Anti-Virus / Hacking. We see not much of electronic warfare in Star Wars, although almost everything runs on computers and droids. Especially for a small rebel force hacking enemy droids or ships would be a preferred tactic. R2D2 is an astromech droid used in space battles. Since droids are a lot more complex then computers in our time, I would infer that anti-virus software is even more complex - so the most secure way is to keep your droids offline! The only interface to communicate with other devices is either a direct hardware link, initiated by your droid, or Binary, which is a limited set of commands - and which can be overheard by people around. No one can silently hack your droid, even if it were possible over the binary interface - they would have to get close enough and talk in binary to your droid and you could stop them.

As for why they speak in binary to humans and not basic - maybe in the droid business binary is even more universally known by engineers across the galaxy than basic ? Maybe it is a lot easier to learn?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why everyone keeps calling it "Binary"...  Binary is "two"...  on & off for instance...  though it could be a 500Hz tone & a 2kHz tone for instance.  But in either event "two".

I've not "analyzed" R2-D2's "speech" with frequency analysis, but in this youtube clip ::

- [BB-8 and R2-D2 Interact](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXHID2sUW_s)

... you can hear the droids communicating & it's definitely not either on/off or only two tones.

That aside, I believe there are two good reasons for an audio handshake:

- an easy "lowest common denominator" way for droids to exchange information
- ○ cheap
- ○ it's omni-directional, yet possible to detect direction
- ○ whether via wireless and/or physical connection, there are many aspects to inter-device communication that would be very hard to standardize across a universe across hundreds/thousands of years.  It's hard enough to have two devices talk across RS232, let alone the myriad of interconnects/protocols possible in the far future
- it's a "monitorable" method, for the organics to observe & quickly interact without special equipment
- it's hard to be attacked by sound for physical damage ... (a rogue droid could send a charge across a direct connect for instance to hurt/attack another droid)

That being said, there's no reason droids couldn't "transfer/upgrade" to a "better/faster" protocol after the initial handshake (similar to how you'd have a modem squak followed by a negotiation of highest speed) if they desired, other than for fictional/story/dramatic purposes.

Comment: Binary is the name of the language, the different tones are just it's encoding. *8')