# Is there an internet equivalent in the Star Wars galaxy?

Tags: star-wars

Is there a canon source that describes a galaxy-wide computer network in the Star Wars galaxy?

Does it mention how big the internet is in the galaxy?

Comment: you mean other than the functions served by the Holonet? http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/HoloNet

Comment: I was thinking the Holonet as well.

Comment: Was the HoloNet just to broadcast news and information to the general public? The link doesn't mention any purpose other than news. Which would make it like CNN or FoxNews, not like the internet.

Comment: HoloNews was news broadcast system over HoloNet... HoloNet was simply a network..

Comment: BTW, The Force is also a galaxy wide network...

Comment: I always thought it was fairly obvious that the galaxy was so technology advanced (droids, hyperspace travel, kolto healing) because they didn't waste so much time on the equivalent of cat memes and farcebook. And to become a Jedi (or Sith) you had to train and study and meditate - and not tweet.

Comment: Related: [Is there Internet in Star Wars?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/76062/49)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**In Disney Canon?  Not really, no.**

The Holonet was a communication network that transmitted holograms around the Empire.  In *Tarkin*, the holonet is restricted to the Empire only, and in various episodes of *Rebels* the plot surrounds taking over broadcast stations to send Rebel propaganda, which makes the Holonet look like cable television.

But the Holonet is also responsible for ship to ship hologrammatic transmissions;  the holograms in *Empire Strikes Back* are Holonet transmissions;  the transmission of Darth Sidius in *The Phantom Menace* also also via Holonet.

(In Legends, it's explained that the Holonet operates in hyperspace, which is why communication is so fast.  Subspace communications are slower, and "mail" only goes the speed of whatever ship it's on.)

Now, we do see droids communicating with comlinks occasionally, so it's not beyond the pale to imagine that droids could connect to each other via comlinks to communicate.

Limiting to Disney Canon, though, computers are treated as monolithic mainframes with huge databases, where data has to be retrieved either online (via connected terminals) or transferred via physical storage (*Rogue One*).  Data transfer is handled by a "sneakernet," with data updates carried by ship to other mainframes, which update their local databases (kinda like usenet newsgroups before the Internet).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning specific source such as *Tarkin* and *Rebels*. Can you provide quotes or scene snippets from those to support your answer? And do the novelizations of *The Empire Strikes Back* and *The Phantom Menace* also mention HoloNets? The best answers are ones that are not just correct, but also mention specific quotes from original sources. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Didn't the Clone Wars TV Series have "DataPad" type things that looked like bulky iPads and connected to Mainframes?

Comment: According to Wookipedia quoting Aftermath, the New Republic abolished the censorship on the Holonet and made it available to everyone. It may then look like the closest equivalent of our Internet.

Comment: Kinda adding on- In the book, Catalyst, when it is talking about Lara's upbringing, it talks about how she was brought up, and that when her parents could afford it, they paid for Holos for her to watch (documentaries and such) as well as in several short stories, some people are referred to as holo stars, so we know there is definitely an "entertainment" side of the "internet".

Answer (score -1):

They have something called the Holo-Net. It seems to only exist in the core worlds region of space (where Coruscant is) because other planets like Tatooine don't have it. Most spaceships seem to be able to access it with their communication systems (like the Millennium Falcon with it's big radar dish), probably to get hyperspace coordinates and to study galaxy chart information (like universal gps for planet locations, like Han does on the Millennium Falcon in Empire Strikes Back).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. The question asked for a canon source, though. Do you have canon source for this answer? If so, please [edit] the answer to cite that source. To quote the OP in [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153417/is-there-an-internet-equivalent-in-the-star-wars-galaxy/260762#comment398101_153464): _"The best answers are ones that are not just correct, but also mention specific quotes from original sources."_