# Has George Lucas or another Star Wars director ever stated that Jar Jar Binks' character was in anyway influenced by C-3PO?

Tags: star-wars, inspiration, character-similarity, c-3po, jar-jar-binks

Both Jar Jar and C-3PO utter this phrase:

> How Rude?

It seems likely to me that Jar Jar and C-3PO serve a similar purpose:

- Comic Effect (C-3PO slightly more refined perhaps, and Jar Jar more slapstick)
- Diplomat to an alien species (Jar Jar to his own Gunguns, C-3PO to the Ewoks.)
- Notionally non-combatants (even if they both fight at some point), which may be easier to relate to.

Did George or a creative director make a deliberate choice in this similarity? Or are they both just fitting an archtype?

Comment: George Lucas recycles lots of phrases, notably "I've got a bad feeling about this". It's his way of 'calling back' to previous films and rewarding loyal viewers.

Comment: You're asking if they're related in character purpose right (such as Uncle Albert being related in this way to Grandad)?

Comment: @MacCooper In the sense that George went 'I need a character like C-3PO/I need a character that does XYZ, I'll model them on C-3PO' and that influenced his Character design

Comment: @Richard if it's just that...I'll take it. I know proving something by an absence of evidence is impossible.

Comment: Uh. The whole bloody thing is infamously archetype based (Capmpbell etc...). Of COURSE they are the same archetype.

Comment: @Pureferret ah im with ya. would have suggested a change in title to relfect that, but uh.... yeah u beat me to it so ill just slink out the back way :D

Comment: vtc since the question is refering to he who must not be named (jar jar)

Comment: Probably not a duplicate, but certainly related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102519/did-george-lucas-ever-comment-on-why-he-created-jar-jar-binks

Comment: @DVK What does soup have to do with SW?

Comment: @Mazura - Google "Campbell + Star Wars" :)

Comment: Man, looking at your questions - you are obsessed on Jar Jar ;)

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo it's such an anomaly in the series

Comment: Technically, Jar Jar says "How Wude!" My son and I have quoted that (with that pronunciation) semi-regularly since seeing the movie. C-3PO's pronunciation wasn't nearly so funny - it just trivially fit the character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Nope.

According to an interview with George Lucas in [TheVulture](http://www.vulture.com/2015/08/george-lucas-says-jar-jar-was-based-on-goofy.html) we learn that Jar Jar was largely inspired by Disney's Goofy;

> *"I can't even begin to tell you how much of an influence Disney has
>   had on me," Lucas told fans at Disney’s D23 expo in Anaheim on Friday.
>   "I will say one secret that nobody knows: **Not many people realize that
>   Goofy was the inspiration for Jar Jar Binks."***

Whereas the major influences behind C-3P0 are [generally acknowledged](http://kitbashed.com/blog/amazing#fn:3) to be evenly split between Akira Kurosawa’s [The Hidden Fortress](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2185/star-wars-and-the-hidden-fortress-comparison) and Fritz Lang’s Metropolis with a healthy dose of McQuarrie's [amazing concept art sketches](http://www.starwars.com/news/an-annotated-guide-to-the-star-wars-portfolio-by-ralph-mcquarrie) and Anthony Daniels' [own input](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2015/sep/03/the-secrecy-has-been-ludicrous-star-wars-actor-anthony-daniels-on-the-new-film-and-his-life-as-c-3po) into [the character](http://www.riverfronttimes.com/musicblog/2009/12/09/a-polite-chat-with-anthony-daniels-the-voice-of-star-wars-c-3po-who-comes-to-st-louis-thursday-for-star-wars-in-concert).

> **Q. C-3PO was original written as sleazy used-car salesman-type of
>   character, but on-screen he was more nervous than anything else. What
>   brought that to the character?**:
>
> **Daniels:** *That was George's idea... he was always [sleazy] in the script, but
>   it's how you interpret [the character]. That's the difference between
>   actors. George never told me he wanted a sleazy guy. So I just looked
>   at it. I had six months working with the script before we started
>   filming because we were making the costumes, so I just interpreted it
>   and George didn't have time to correct me. I'm afraid 3PO stayed the
>   way he was. He is 3PO, he isn't me. He is this strange creation that
>   came out of somewhere*